# Twitter API - quick summary

Tags: api, twitter

For a project, I wan't to build a webapp, which shows (semi-) real time Tweets with specific keywords.
I'm not sure how to start. Can somebody explain to me how I need to start. I have a PHP framework for my website.

- With what language do I need to retrieve data form the Twitter API. JSON? PHP?
- Where can I find a nice tutorial?

I hope somebody can provide me a few lines of code, just to help me on the right track.

Thanks!
- Sammy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis) with the [Phirehose](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose) library (PHP).

The method "filter" of this API catch all the tweets with the specified keywords in real-time. You can take a look at [140dev](http://140dev.com/) for an example of application using this library.

Comment: You're right. I already found this framework myself and it does exactly what I need. Thanks!